# How can to make upload exception while loading csv file to Vertica?

Tags: python, vertica

at current moment time I load csv file to Vertica using this script

```
connection = vertica_python.connect(**conn_info)
cursor = connection.cursor()
with open("C:\DataBases\csv\%s_%s.csv" % (FILE_NAME, TABLE_NAME), "rb") as fs:
my_file = fs.read()
cursor.copy("COPY %s.%s from stdin PARSER fcsvparser(type='traditional', delimiter=';', record_terminator='\n',)" %(SCHEMA_NAME, TABLE_NAME), my_file)
connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

BUT this variant Does not show exceptions.

I want to upload execptions into File, but I run this script not on vertica server, on my local server.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use REJECTED DATA AS TABLE option and then query the table.
Also you can use NO COMMIT option to force vertica created the table as temp table

something like this:

```
my_file = fs.read()
cursor.copy("COPY t from stdin rejected data as table t_rej direct NO COMMIT", my_file)
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM t_rej ")
for row in cursor.iterate():
    print(row)
# do something
connection.commit()
# t_rej automatic removed by vertica
connection.close()
```

Comment: I must will create table "t_rej" before exceute COPY and "t" must same "t_rej"?

Comment: you can use any name you want for rejected data table, vertica will create it. in case of NO COMMIT copy it will created as temp table and vertica will drop it after commit/rollback. If you will use regular auto commited copy table will be created once and vertica will reuse it (also the "rejected" data will remain in table)